# Signification of '-z "${line}"' in if condition

Tags: shell-script

What does -z "${line}" mean in the if condition of the following code:

```
while read line
do
if [ -z "${line}" ]; then
echo "file empty "
exit
fi
done < $FILE
```

Please let me know what exactly what the if condition is checking.

Comment: You might want to read the following, it desctibes all the options for bash if statements and what they do: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is testing if the variable `$line` (equivalent here to `${line}`) is empty (containing no chararacters).  You would get that case when the `read` operation reaches the end of the file.

A followup comment asked what the `z` is for (what it means).  The **`[`** operator corresponds to the [**`test`** utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), with POSIX stating

> **`-z`**  *string*
>       True if the length of string string is ***zero***; otherwise, false.

so the `-z` was probably chosen originally for its mnemonic value.  It was not provided in the oldest version of [`test`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/1/test) (Unix 7th, 1979), but appeared in the [8th edition](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/test) (1985):

```
-z s1    true if the length of string s1 is zero.
```

Because it was undocumented in the 7th edition, but appeared around the same time in 3BSD (file dated February 1979 in CSRG CD1), it appears to have from from BSD.

Not all of the options in `test` have an obvious relationship between the letter and meaning.  This one came fairly early, so it was possible to choose a letter which can be related to the meaning.

Comment: and what is the -z for ??

Comment: like zero ? : the length of STRING is zero